# Joomla Language Switcher Missing Language

Tags: joomla3.0, multilingual

I am developing and multi language website (3 Languages - Default :English)
I have another two Languages but on my Language Switcher I can only see one of them.

For the default Language the issue I think is the following:
On the menus drop down i **can see all flags except the default one** as I am not allowed to change the default page (Home Page) of that menu to English. When I try to do it i get the following error:
"Save failed with the following error: The Language parameter for this menu item must be set to 'All'. At least one Default menu item must have Language set to All, even if the site is multilingual."

I haven't been able to understand why I can't see the 3rd Language even if I had followed the exact same procedure with the visible one.

Attaching the link with the instructions I have followed: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm114SqvUuc

Any help on troubleshooting?